# Block width increase direction?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a header that consists of three parts. The header is set to `display: flex` and `justify-content` is set to space-between.

I want the input element to increase when focused without moving other elements in the header.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px;

}

.search__input {
  width: 60px;
  transition: width 0.1s ease;
}

.search__input:focus {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <div>Left</div>

  <div>Center</div>

  <div class="header__search">
    <input class="search__input" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>

</header>
```

I was thinking about `position: absolute` when focused, but I don't know how to realize it.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer (and click the accept checkmark to show others that it was your chosen solution), not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear question in sentence format. It makes no sense as it is. See [ask]. Also, take the [tour] so you know how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself using `position: absolute` and `float: right`.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px;

}
.header__search {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}
.search__input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 60px;
  transition: width 0.1s ease;
}

.search__input:focus {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <div>Left</div>

  <div>Center</div>

  <div class="header__search">
    <input class="search__input" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set an explicit width on the children if you don't want them to re-size dynamically.

This solution also requires setting additional classes and properties on the other children to get them to behave exactly as you want to. There may be a more elegant flexbox-based solution available.

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px;
}
.header div {
    width: 20vw;
    text-align: center;
}
.header div:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.search__input {
    width: 60px;
    transition: width 0.1s ease;
    float: right;
}
.search__input:focus {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div>Left</div>
    <div>Center</div>
    <div class="header__search">
        <input class="search__input" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
</header>
```

I set the input box to float to the right; you could achieve this with positioning and directional properties if you want, instead.

I also set the text-alignment for the other two divs to have them display the way you have them set in your code above.